# storing random numbers in database in php?

Tags: php, database

I have some code which generates random number like some discount coupon code. Every time list of new codes are generated and I want it to be saved in database, each and every time new list is generated and so I want that to be saved in database.

```
 <?php
 $db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','shop');
     if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Could not connect to database:Plz try After Some time..';
        exit;
        }

$coupons = 8; //number of coupons
$size = 10; //number of characters
for ($i=0; $i<$coupons; $i++) {
    $code=

   echo strtoupper(substr(md5(time().rand(10000,99999)), 0, $size));
   echo "<br>\n";

   $qry="insert into code (code) values ('$coupons')";
   $result=$db->query($qry);

}
```

Comment: Is this actually the code that you are using? `$code=` should be giving you a parse error.

Comment: that's a mistake i am sorry for that

Comment: that should break the script because you have no value or an ending semi-colon. change INSERT INTO to INSERT INTO `code` SET `field` = $value. also, you want to store the random number, not $coupons, it'll only insert 8, you want to store random numbers. Put strtoupper part in a variable then use it in the INSERT statement.

Comment: can u explain little more in detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this code is not running for you - try the below where I've made a couple changes:

```
$coupons = 8; //number of coupons
$size = 10; //number of characters
for ($i=0; $i<$coupons; $i++) {
   // Note that time() is not a very good random generator...
   $code= strtoupper(substr(md5(time().rand(10000,99999)), 0, $size));
   $qry="insert into code (code) values ('$code')";
   $result=$db->query($qry);
}
```

Comment: but i have one doubt left values on browser are different as compared to stored in database can u explain reason for that..

Comment: Since my code (above) doesn't display anything in a browser it's a little hard for me to answer that question...

Comment: `$result=$db->query($qry); echo $code;` @AnmolSinghRaghuvanshi - The generated code will match what's being entered in your database.